# getting 0.0000 when converting NSString value to float

Tags: objective-c, floating-point, nsstring

In my application, i tried to convert NSString value to float using

```
NSString *value = [dict objectForKey:@"student_Percentage"];
float f = [value floatValue];
```

But I'm getting the value of f as 0.00000. I tried with NSNumberFormatter, NSNumber... but still get 0.00000.

Comment: When you `NSLog` the `value`, what do you receive?

Comment: What about if you `NSLog` the `dict`?

Comment: @smily: Did you get `76.5432` or `"76.5432"` (i.e. are the quotes part of the value)? Because the latter would explain the `0` value.

Comment: I got dict data as student_Percentage = "\"76.5432\"";

Comment: " is not valid text representation of a floating-point number.

Comment: got "76.5432" when I NSLog 'value' and student_Percentage = "\"76.5432\"" when I NSLog 'dict'

Comment: How to convert it to valid string representation?

Comment: It looks like your string actually includes the quotes (hence the escape character in the log), so that's why it can't do the conversion

Comment: [value replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@"" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [value length])];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> floatValue  returns 0.0 if the receiver doesn’t begin with a valid
>   text representation of a floating-point number.

`[dict objectForKey:@"student_Percentage"]` value should be like 8.9.
Remove double quotes from your string.

```
NSMutableString *value = [dict objectForKey:@"student_Percentage"];
[value replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@"" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [value length])];
float f = [value floatValue];
```

Comment: what is return value of replaceOccurrencesOfString:withString:options:range?

Answer (score 0):

Hey i think your dict value has a problem. Try this code it gives the correct value.

```
NSString *temp = @"25.38";
float p = [temp floatValue];
NSLog(@"%f",p);
```

Or maybe use `valueforkey` instead of `objectForKey`.