# Something goes wrong when I convert NSString to float

Tags: ios, floating-point, nsstring, type-conversion

Something goes wrong when I convert NSString to float. I got zero value, but why?

```
NSString *polylineStr = @"51.351305,-0.024239;51.374855,-0.092412";
NSArray *strPolylineArr = [polylineStr componentsSeparatedByString:@";"];
for ( NSString *str in strPolylineArr) {

    NSArray *arr = [str componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
    NSString *firstString = [arr firstObject];
    NSLog(@"__str %@ float %f", [arr firstObject], [firstString floatValue]);
}
```

my output is

```
__str 51.351305 float 0.000000
__str 51.374855 float 51.374855
```

I found that something wrong with first string.

[image]

Comment: check out this answer.  There might be extra characters in the first string.  Possibly the \x  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11624900/getting-0-0000-when-converting-nsstring-value-to-float

Comment: When i copy pasted your code into notepad i see an extra character in front of 51 and at the of 39.  It doesn't show up when i copy paste into comments.   Check if you get the same and that might be the reason floatvalue return 0

Comment: Yan, yes I need remove extra character, like replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"\x10" withString:@""

Comment: remove "\x10" or use below code

Answer (score 0):

HI in your string some character add : '' you can't see but copy character which is on single quote or use below code:

```
NSString *polylineStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"51.351305,-0.024239;51.374855,-0.092412"];
    NSArray *strPolylineArr = [polylineStr componentsSeparatedByString:@";"];
    for ( NSString *str in strPolylineArr) {

        NSArray *arr = [str componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
        NSString *firstString = [arr firstObject];
        NSLog(@"__str %@ float %f", [arr firstObject], [firstString floatValue]);
    }
```